# invoking ngSubmit from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

Hello I have a directive that changes tabs on click of a button. I just want to invoke the ngSubmit for form validation from inside the directive. Is it possible?

Directive

```
angular.module 'myapp'
.directive 'nextButton', [() ->
  return {
    restrict: 'A'
    replace: true  
    transclude: false
    scope: {
      saveLocal: '&saveDataLocal'
      nextTab: '='
    }
    link: (scope, elem, attrs) -> 
      console.log scope.saveLocal
      elem.bind 'click', ()->
        console.log attrs
        scope.saveLocal 'app'
        angular.element('#'+scope.nextTab).trigger('click')
  }
]
```

my html in jade templating:

```
form#generalFormScc(name="form" ng-submit="saveForm(form, $event)")
  input(type='text', placeholder='Name', ng-model="name", required)
  button(next-button next-tab="'next'" save-data-local="ngSubmit" form-name="'generalFormScc'") Next
```

here,
next-tab is the id for triggering next tab,
save-data-local should trigger the ngSubmit

I know I can directly call the saveForm() from directive, but I want default html validation aswell. So I want to trigger ngSubmit.

Is there any way?thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found out I could just get the id of the form and call submit method on it For future reference.

```
'use strict'

angular.module 'myApp'
.directive 'nextButton', [() ->
  return {
    restrict: 'A'
    replace: true  
    transclude: false
    scope: {
      saveLocal: '&saveDataLocal'
      nextTab: '='
      formName : '='
    }
    link: (scope, elem, attrs) -> 
      console.log scope.saveLocal
      elem.bind 'click', ()->
        angular.element('#'+scope.formName).submit()
        if not angular.element('#'+scope.formName).hasClass 'ng-invalid'
          angular.element('#'+scope.nextTab).trigger('click')
  }
]
```